# Angular sticky navbar without brutal transition

Tags: angular, css-transitions, navbar, sticky

I have a problem when I put the navbar in "sticky" state, when I exceed the default position of the navbar it only reverts to its normal state when I am at the top of the page, which causes a "brutal" transition.

How can I do so as not to have this abrupt transition, no matter how hard I look, but I can't find any solution or it doesn't work.

Here is the stackblitz link which shows the preview (move the bar by hand and not with the wheel to really see the brutal effect): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-raebek?file=src/app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the built in CSS `position: sticky`, that will take care of it for you assuming you are ok with its compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility

Here's an udpated stack blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oej69x?file=src/app/navbar/navbar.component.css

We need to use angular's `:host` selector to set this style on the `app-navbar` element. It needs to be a block level element (Angular defaults to inline), have `position: sticky` and a `top` number of where you want it to stick, in our case 0.  Then we get rid of all your JS class setting in the component scroll listner

Add this to **navbar.component.css**

```css
/* we can use the built in CSS sticky feature, but we must do it on the app-navbar element so we use :host */
:host {
  display: block;
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice ! Thank you so much, i didn't know 'host' selector, besides, I don't really understand how it works, I'll do some research on it :)

Comment: When you make a component in Angular, the selector in your component decorator (usually "app-component-name") is the DOM element that everything in your component will be put into.  Sometimes, you need styles directly on that element, and Angular has that special `:host` selector for that purpose.

Comment: There's also a lot of other cool stuff you can do with HostBindings in Angular like set classes and properties on that host element https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding